# Loading a class dynamically from within a Java Library

Tags: java

I implemented a library "core" and two wrapper libraries "w1" and "w2" that contain "core". Each one of the wrapper libraries has an implementation class com.example.impl.ImplementationClass defined.

My core library needs to dynamically load the implementation class from the wrapper. The way I did it was just call Class.forname("com.example.impl.ImplementationClass") but I get a ClassNotFoundException.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Could we get some sample code of all the imports? And the line where the error is thrown? And the full stacktrace?

Comment: And make sure that the wrapper libraries are in your classpath?